# php preg_match excluding text within html tags/attributes to find correct place to cut a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to determine the absolute position of certain words within a block of html, but only if they are outside of an actual html tag. For instance, if I wanted to determine the position of the word "join" using preg_match in this text:

```
<p>There are 14 more days until our <a href="/somepage.html" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" aria-label="join us">holiday special</a> so come join us!</p>
```

I could use:

```
preg_match('/join/', $post_content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset);
```

The problem is that this is matching the word within the aria-label attribute, when what I need is the one just after the link. It would be fine to match between the `<a>` and `</a>`, just not inside the brackets themselves.

My actual end goal, most of what (I think) I have aside from this last element: I am trimming a block of html (not a full document) to cut off at a specific word count. I am trying to determine which character that last word ends at, and then joining the left side of the html block with only the html from the right side, so all html tags close gracefully. I thought I had it working until I ran into an example like I showed where the last word was also within an html attribute, causing me to split the string at the wrong location. This is my code so far:

```
$post_content = strip_tags ( $p->post_content, "<a><br><p><ul><li>" );
$post_content_stripped = strip_tags ( $p->post_content );
$post_content_stripped = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", ' ', $post_content_stripped);
$post_content_stripped = preg_replace("/\s+/", ' ', $post_content_stripped);
$post_content_stripped_array = explode ( " " , trim($post_content_stripped) );
$excerpt_wordcount = count( $post_content_stripped_array );
$cutpos = 0;
while($excerpt_wordcount>48){
    $thiswordrev = "/" . strrev($post_content_stripped_array[$excerpt_wordcount - 1]) . "/";
    preg_match($thiswordrev, strrev($post_content), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $cutpos);
    $cutpos = $matches[0][1] + (strlen($thiswordrev) - 2);
    array_pop($post_content_stripped_array);
    $excerpt_wordcount = count( $post_content_stripped_array );
}
if($pwordcount>$excerpt_wordcount){
    preg_match_all('/<\/?[^>]*>/', substr( $post_content, strlen($post_content) - $cutpos ), $closetags_result);
    $excerpt_closetags = "" . $closetags_result[0][0];
    $post_excerpt = substr( $post_content, 0, strlen($post_content) - $cutpos ) . $excerpt_closetags;
}else{
    $post_excerpt = $post_content;
}
```

I am actually searching the string in reverse in this case, since I am walking word by word backwards from the end of the string, so I know that my html brackets are backwards, eg:

```
>p/<!su nioj emoc os >a/<laiceps yadiloh>"su nioj"=lebal-aira "renepoon rerreferon"=ler "knalb_"=tegrat "lmth.egapemos/"=ferh a< ruo litnu syad erom 41 era erehT>p<
```

But it's easy enough to flip all of the brackets before doing the preg_match, or I am assuming should be easy enough to have the preg_match account for that.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2):

Do not use regex to parse HTML.

You have a simple objective: limit the text content to a given number of words, ensuring that the HTML remains valid.

To this end, I would suggest looping through text nodes until you count a certain number of words, and then removing everything after that.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($post_content);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$all_text_nodes = $xpath->query("//text()");
$words_left = 48;
foreach( $all_text_nodes as $text_node) {
    $text = $text_node->textContent;
    $words = explode(" ", $text); // TODO: maybe preg_split on /\s/ to support more whitespace types
    $word_count = count($words);
    if( $word_count < $words_left) {
        $words_left -= $word_count;
        continue;
    }
    // reached the threshold
    $words_that_fit = implode(" ", array_slice($words, 0, $words_left));
    // If the above TODO is implemented, this will need to be adjusted to keep the specific whitespace characters
    $text_node->textContent = $words_that_fit;

    $remove_after = $text_node;
    while( $remove_after->parentNode) {
        while( $remove_after->nextSibling) {
            $remove_after->parentNode->removeChild($remove_after->nextSibling);
        }
        $remove_after = $remove_after->parentNode;
    }
    break;
}
$output = substr($dom->saveHTML($dom->getElementsByTagName("body")->item(0)), strlen("<body>"), -strlen("</body>"));
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/dOtqM)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out a workaround. I don't know if this is the most elegant solution, so if someone sees a better one I would still love to hear it, but for now I realized that I don't have to actually have the html in the string I am searching to determine the position to cut, I just need it to be the same length. I grabbed all of the html elements and just created a dummy string replacing all of them with the same number of asterisks:

```
// create faux string with placeholders instead of html for search purposes
preg_match_all('/<\/?[^>]*>/', $post_content, $alltags_result);
$tagcount = count( $alltags_result );
$post_content_dummy = $post_content;
foreach($alltags_result[0] as $thistag){
    $post_content_dummy = str_replace($thistag, str_repeat("*",strlen($thistag)), $post_content_dummy);
}
```

Then I just use `$post_content_dummy` in the while loop instead of `$post_content`, in order to find the cut position, and then `$post_content` for the actual cut. So far seems to be working fine.